# TeamSpeak has everything muted in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio

Ever since the release of 12.04, TeamSpeak has not been allowing me to talk or hear.

It shows that I have my speakers and my microphone muted/disabled. Could this have something to do with PulseAudio?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Teamspeak uses ALSA by default. try switching to pulseaudio. Should resolve it.

If no audio on your system is working. try the following...

Check under sound setting/hardware.( you can search in unity and gnome for "Sound")
 if your rig has multiple choices, make sure you have the correct one selected.

Also, if this is a dual boot system. log back into other OS and use the keyboard Hot keys to make sure it's un-muted. ( I had this issue. apparently my card was muted in the hardware not software side. )

reboot into 12.04 and see if that changed it. :)

Also you could try checking opening terminal (ctrl+Alt+T) or search terminal in the gui.
once in terminal type: alsamixer
make sure all the bars are green. if any are not. navigate to them with the arrow keys and press "M" to toggle mute on/Off

I hope you figure it out. good luck.